# Is there a way to load a class file to assembly in runtime?

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to do something that gets a cs file in runtime from user make it meaningful to assembly get its properties, methods etc.

Is there a way to do this by reflection in C#?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To compile a file on the fly you'll need to do something along these lines (where sourceCode is a string containg the code to compile):

```
CodeDomProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
ICodeCompiler compiler = codeProvider.CreateCompiler();

// add compiler parameters
CompilerParameters compilerParams = new CompilerParameters();
compilerParams.CompilerOptions = "/target:library /optimize";
compilerParams.GenerateExecutable = false;
compilerParams.GenerateInMemory = true;         
compilerParams.IncludeDebugInformation = false;
compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("mscorlib.dll");
compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");

// compile the code
CompilerResults results = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParams, sourceCode);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can compile it reasonably easily using the [CSharpCodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx). You can download the source code for my snippet compiler, Snippy, from the [C# in Depth web site](http://csharpindepth.com/Downloads.aspx). That uses CSharpCodeProvider, so you could use it as sample code.